# Trying to get a token not currently working

Tags: symfony, jwt, token, api-platform.com

I am trying to put a JWT Auth to access my API : /api/docs
But I am currently getting an error while trying to get the token with this command :

```sh
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" http://localhost/login_check -d '{"username":"johndoe","password":"test"}'
```

Of course I replace username and password

> Signature key "/var/www/config/jwt/private.pem" does not
>   exist or is not readable. Did you correctly set the
>   "lexik_jwt_authentication.signature_key" configuration key?
>   (500 Internal Server Error)

security.yaml

```
    firewalls:
        login:
            pattern:  ^/login
            stateless: true
            anonymous: true
            provider: fos_userbundle_2
            json_login:
                check_path: /login_check
                username_path: username
                password_path: password
                success_handler: 
    lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_success
                failure_handler: 
    lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_failure

        main:
            pattern:   ^/
            provider: fos_userbundle_2
            stateless: true
            anonymous: true
            guard:
                authenticators:
                    - lexik_jwt_authentication.jwt_token_authenticator

        dev:
            pattern:  ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false
```

> Signature key "/var/www/config/jwt/private.pem" does not
>   exist or is not readable. Did you correctly set the
>   "lexik_jwt_authentication.signature_key" configuration key?
>   (500 Internal Server Error)

Comment: The doc is quite clear about that. https://github.com/lexik/LexikJWTAuthenticationBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/index.md#generate-the-ssh-keys

Comment: so, you can't create the private and public key, or what

Answer (score 9):

Check privilages for reading and writing to files generated by openssl.

```
$ mkdir -p config/jwt
$ openssl genpkey -out config/jwt/private.pem -aes256 -algorithm rsa -pkeyopt rsa_keygen_bits:4096
$ openssl pkey -in config/jwt/private.pem -out config/jwt/public.pem -pubout
```

In my case before:

```
-rw-------    1 root     root          3434 Jul 26 21:21 private.pem
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root           800 Jul 26 21:21 public.pem
```

Then I run

```
chmod 644 public.pem private.pem
```

Now:

```
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root          3434 Jul 26 21:21 private.pem
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root           800 Jul 26 21:21 public.pem
```

and it works.

---

Docs:

https://github.com/lexik/LexikJWTAuthenticationBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/index.md#generate-the-ssh-keys

Comment: Perfect! Change file permissions solved my problem too

Answer (score 2):

In my local env -rw------- access works well, but in prod only -rw-r--r-- works so I think if you run into this problem and are sure you have already created pem files, you should change the permissions on private.pem and it will work as expected.